# "he said no to anything containing sugar" or "he said no to everything containing sugar"?

Tags: word-usage

> In short
>   Sugar is the root of every disease
>   So we should avoid it
>   A man had cancer at the age of 45
>   and he just said no to any thing
>   containing sugar and carbonated
>   drinks and now is aging 45 and never
>   became ill in these 20 years and just
>   got minor flue once.
>   Moral
>   We should quit sugar..
>
> *now is aging 75

I don't know which sounds more correct but I think the latter is the one to go with.

Comment: Hi Abdul, and welcome to ELL (however involuntarily). Text in images can't be indexed by search or read by anyone using screen reader software or similar, so we generally ask people to transcribe any text from images that they need in order to ask their question.

Comment: Google Books claims over 600,000 written instances of [***anything and everything***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22anything+and+everything%22) Similar to collocations like ***aid and abet*** and ***cease and desist,*** it's effectively repetition for "emphasis" rather than "completeness" (to all intents and purposes, the two terms are equivalent). In short - *both* your suggestions are perfectly fine, and if you wanted to be more emphatic you could write *He said no to **anything and everything** containing sugar.*

Comment: Could you please add more detail explaining what *you* think is the difference, and why you think one is better than the other?  Otherwise this question should be closed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - reminds me of a department I was in which was developing "aims and objectives". I was tempted to support the aims, but oppose the objectives.

Comment: @fred2: I suppose you wouldn't have offered to *aid* those with aims, but *abet* those with objectives? :)

Answer (score 1):

> **..anything containing sugar.
>
>   ..everything containing sugar.**

Both are good grammar.

Both are easily understood.

The second version is a little bit more emphatic.
It is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of the two is the same, but I would say that the precise meaning is different. They lead to the same thing in the end, though.

> he just said no to **anything** containing sugar

This means that he refused any time he was offered something containing sugar.

> he just said no to **everything** containing sugar

This means that he pro-actively decided that he would have nothing with sugar.

The difference is subtle, this understanding may not be consistent between native speakers, and it doesn't really matter because it amounts to the same thing in the end.

***Anything*** and ***everything*** are different words and have different meanings, but not infrequently the overall sense of a sentence is the same with either. Do not make the mistake of thinking they are interchangeable generally, though. After all, you wouldn't want to ask someone:

> Can I get you everything?